# Different types of filtering in R

Tags: r, filter, pipe

There are 3 options I have seen to filter.

With pipes:

```
    starwars %>% filter(skin_color == "light", eye_color == "brown")
```

and without pipes:

```
    starwars[starwars$skin_color == "light" & starwars$eye_color == "brown", ]
```

again without pipes,

```
    filter(starwars, skin_color == "light" & eye_color == "brown")
```

Three ways worked perfectly,

What is the difference between them?

Comment: All of the 3 methods are valid, and when it comes which one to use -> this depends on personal preference and readability in the specific context. The first and last use `dplyr` package. First one with the pipe operator, the last one direct the `filter` function from `dplyr`. The second one uses base R with `[` and `]` to subset.

Comment: still more ways: `subset(starwars, skin_color == "light" & eye_color == "brown")` base R

Comment: `lhs %>% rhs` passes `lhs` into the first argumet of `rhs`. E.g. you cam re-write `sum(1:10)` as `1:10 %>% sum()`. So your first and third codes are basically equivalent. The second one uses `[` to extract parts of an object that fulfill a certain condition. In this case you can think of `filter` and `[` as different tools to achieve the same goal. Using which one depends on your preference.